# Spring MVC and tiles -- how to set non-boolean "true/false" to checkbox

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, tags, jstl, tiles

I have a web application with back end table has a column called `type` and another column called `value`. `type` indicates the components type (textfield, combobox, checkbox..etc), `value` is the actual value of the component, both columns are VARCHAR2.

The challenge is, when the type is `combobox`, then the `value` of the component is either `true` or `false` in String. And I have no privilege to modify the database attribute.

Then when I put a checkbox on the front end:

```
<field:checkbox field="enableEditing.setting" id="systemsetting_${formSettings.enableEditing.name}" z="user-managed"/>
```

I get the following exception:

```
Attribute 'value' is required when binding to non-boolean values
```

even I make a `value` attribute in the `checkbox.tagx`,

```
<field:checkbox field="enableEditing.setting" id="systemsetting_${formSettings.enableEditing.name}" value="${formSettings.enableEditing.setting}" z="user-managed"/>
```

I still have the same exception.

It seems like if the field is not a `boolean` type, then there is no way to make the checkbox work.

But I know I must break something, so please enlighten me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Any solutions? I have exactly the same issue, http://stackoverflow.com/q/41642588/1005607